# What should be selected for universal size "Retina 3.5 fullscreen" or "Retina 4 fullscreen"?

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, interface-builder, xib

I am working in XCode Version 4.5. For each Xib I can select the size as either "Retina 3.5 fullscreen" or "Retina 4 fullscreen".

My doubt is: will my app work properly on an older iPhone (with screen with 3.5) if I select Retina 4 Fullscreen and vice-versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to Create separate Xib files for Both 3.5" and 4" screen and load them as per device version.Also You can SET `autoresizingMask`  See the following code :

`UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`

Answer (score 2):

US 3.5 retina and set autoresizing mask as required
You can set autoresizing mask by XIB also

Answer (score 0):

Those options under Simulated Metrics don't impact the application itself, it's just a way to *preview* how it will look in Xcode under those conditions.

You could use different Xibs/Storyboards depending on which screen size the device is, but in my experience, most apps could pretty trivially use a single Xib/Storyboard (there's generally an element that can just be made larger, such as a table or scroll view... I've had more than a few Just Work). Much easier than duplicating the UI, *and* keeping any tweak made in sync between the two versions. There might be some cases where the duplication is worth it, but they're not the majority.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the autoresizing masks are set correctly, the display should align itself perfectly irrespective of the end device it is deployed to. The sizes are just to give you a perspective of how the xib's would look like on a 3.5" or 4". Nonetheless, it's advisable to test on all available devices you wish to support. For your question, 3.5" & autoresizing should suffice to work perfectly on both sets of devices. HTH.